# call aspnet_Delete_User SP in trigger

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, asp.net-membership

I have a trigger in students table that deletes related records from other tables when i delete a student. I want to delete student's membership data by calling aspnet_delete_user stored procedure in the trigger . but this works just if I delete one student . and if I remover multiple students in one query it doesn't work .

How to call this SP for multi-row operation trigger ?

Comment: What parameters does `aspnet_delete_user` take? Which parameter maps to which column that would be found in the `inserted` pseudo-table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to use a cursor or build a dynamic SQL string (which uses a cursor without saying so). Alternatively, you could copy the logic from the stored procedure and see if you can tailor it to become set-based - I haven't looked at the procedure, so I'm not sure if this is feasible, practical or even possible, but it's the first thing I try to do before adding cursors or dynamic SQL to a trigger.

For a cursor, something like this (I'm guessing you pass a GUID or something to the procedure, but I have no idea):

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.StudentAfterDelete
ON dbo.Students
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @MemberID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

  DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
    FOR SELECT MemberID FROM deleted;

  OPEN c;

  FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @MemberID;

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
  BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.aspnet_delete_user @MemberID;

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @MemberID;
  END

  CLOSE c;
  DEALLOCATE c;
END
GO
```

Dynamic SQL, same assumptions:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.StudentAfterDelete
ON dbo.Students
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

  SELECT @sql += 'EXEC dbo.aspnet_delete_user ''' 
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), MemberID) + ''';' FROM deleted;

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO
```

However including the missing information up front is more useful. Don't assume that everyone who works with SQL Server has any clue what aspnet_delete_user does.

Comment: well my problem with the procedure is that it takes one username as parameter so if I delete multiple students I don't know how to pass these usernames to this Sp . using a loop ? or .. ?

Comment: @reza thank you for correcting this, but my goal wasn't for you to change the accepted answer, just to explain how you made your decision, because it didn't follow the guidelines for the site. Please review http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19448/etiquette-for-selecting-answers and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19585/accepting-a-duplicate-answer-etiquette in full.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TheNameOfTheTrigger
ON YourTableYouWantToTriggerOn
AFTER DELETE 
AS
   DECLARE @yourPrimaryKey int

    DECLARE delete_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT
        yourPrimaryKey
    FROM
        deleted

    OPEN delete_cursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM delete_cursor 
    INTO @yourPrimaryKey

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
       EXEC aspnet_delete_user @yourPrimaryKey
       FETCH NEXT FROM delete_cursor INTO @yourPrimaryKey
    END

    CLOSE delete_cursor
    DEALLOCATE delete_cursor
GO
```

See more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258831%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258831%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)